# HBase: Create table with same schema as existing table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, mapr, hbase-shell

I tried searching on the forum, where I can create a new empty hbase table from existing hbase table schema, but not able to find.

To be more precise, suppose I have a table with multiple column families and many column qualifier within those families.

Now I have to create another empty table with the same schema. Do we any way to create table like we do in RDBMS.

```
Create table new_table as
select * from existing_table where 1=2;
```

The existing table has a complex structure, so normal hbase `create table` command with column family and column qualifier specified is not an option.

FYI.. I am using `Mapr HBase 0.98.12-mapr-1506` and I do not have option to switch to any advance version or another distribution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the full-proof approach, I used. Hope it will help other people.

1) launch HBase shell vial below command

```
 hbase shell
```

2)  Query existing table metadata with below command

```
 hbase> describe ‘existing_table’;
```

Output would be similar to:

```
{NAME => 'cf1', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING 
=> 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION
_SCOPE => '0'}                                                                                                                  
{NAME => 'cf2', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING 
=> 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION
_SCOPE => '0'}
```

3) Copy this output to a notepad and do below changes:

```
  a) Replace  TTL => 'FOREVER' with TTL => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants::FOREVER
  b) Put an additional comma (,) between each column family description to connect column family definition.
  c) Remove newline characters (\n, \r) for the text; such that the content become one line text.
```

4) Finally running the create query with new table name:

```
create ‘copy_of_exsting_table_schema’, {NAME => 'cf1', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING 
=> 'NONE', TTL => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants::FOREVER, COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION
_SCOPE => '0'} ,{NAME => 'cf2', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING 
=> 'NONE', TTL => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants::FOREVER, COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION
_SCOPE => '0'}
```

And you are done. The new table schema is exactly same as existing table.

Comment: This will help to create the new schema with existing schema, how we will copy the data with existing table and schema also

Comment: Use snapshot feature to clone hbase table.

Answer (score 11):

you can use snapshot feature to do this. like this;

```
hbase> snapshot 'tableName', 'tableSnapshot'
hbase> clone_snapshot 'tableSnapshot', 'newTableName'
hbase> delete_snapshot 'tableSnapshot'
hbase> truncate 'newTableName'
```

i hope your table is not huge. And you can not copy column qualifiers with empty values, if i did not understand wrong, you mean this in your question. you can either copy all data to new table or only table structure with column families, coprocessors.. etc.

Comment: Thanks for response, just wanted to understand, what `disable 'tableName'` would do. I do not have option to make the original table offline (can't stop read/write from other program). I just need schema, not interested into data to be copied. Can we just make a new schema copy using snapshot feature?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my answer. you don't need to disable table to run snapshot command.

Comment: This is supported by reading the snapshot section of the HBase book: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots

Comment: it is 4 years old question and showing a workaround not giving exact code to do what he is asking.